# how to set value for column from another column when insert from django admin form

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have book stock form and it has two columns to indicate the the stock value:
current stock, and the stock,
current stock and stock should be the same when inserting the first time,
but, when borrow a book the current stock should be decreased, and the stock column will be at the first value:
for instance:
book1 has stock 5 and current stock 5,
someone borrowed the book1, so
book1 stock 5 and current stock 4,

I don't want to do it from database triggers because my application is database independent.

please help me how can I do it from django admin form?

models.py:

```
class BooksCopy(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    no_of_copies = models.IntegerField('Stock')
    current_no_of_copies = models.IntegerField('Current Stock')
```

admin.py:

```
class BooksCopiesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    models.BooksCopy.current_no_of_copies = models.BooksCopy.no_of_copies
    exclude = ('current_no_of_copies',)
    list_display = ('branch', 'book', 'no_of_copies', 'current_no_of_copies',)
```

Comment: What do you mean by " how can I do it from django admin form?" ? Do you want your users to login to admin forms to borrow books or you have a custom templates prepared? Also we would need to see your model to hold transaction data for the borrowing books.

Comment: Yes, I would need the users to login to the admin forms to borrow books:
I can do it easily in DB trigger before insert as the following: 
new.current_no_of_copies = new.no_of_copies;

but I need to do it from the interface.

Comment: Django's admin console is very comprehensive and customizable so users often think to utilize the admin console. But it's not a great practice. Admin console should only be accessible to the admin user for backend data access and manipulation. Better to create a custom page for the normal user logins and have a signals or save method overrides to replace your DB trigger logic in the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have some class holding borrowed books and by which user.  Something like

```
class BorrowedBooks(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can now

```
class BooksCopy(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    no_of_copies = models.IntegerField('Stock')

    @property
    def current_no_of_copies (self):
        return self.no_of_copies - self.borrowedbooks_set.all()
```